# Why there is a folder tests in a root of yii2 framework?

Tags: yii2, phpunit, codeception

It is basic template. 
I use this command to generate test file and run:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/codecept generate:test unit Example
$ ./vendor/bin/codecept run
```

This file appears in folder /vendor/bin/tests/unit.
I can't push this file to GitHub. 
Why test files appear in vendor folder? What Should I do to make test files save in tests folder in the root of the project?

Comment: And run test files from the root

Comment: What is a value of paths: tests: setting in codeception.yml file?

Comment: paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support

Comment: I cannot fault your codeception.yml file - it is default... works for me with Basic Yii2 template

Comment: @drAnton I have posted an answer for you, please let me know if it helps. If so, please consider marking as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to debug your paths and resolve the config issue that is causing this.

The path used is set on line 45 of file: `vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Command/GenerateTest.php`

There you will see this code, which creates the new directory:

`$path = $this->createDirectoryFor($config['path'], $class);`

The value of `$config['path']` is determined in method `suiteSettings`, line 285 in file `vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Configuration.php`

Here you will see this code, which sets the path for the config:

```
    $settings['path'] = self::$dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $config['paths']['tests']
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $settings['path'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Add the following code before these 2 lines:

```
    echo 'self::$dir ' . print_r(self::$dir, true) . PHP_EOL;
    echo '$config[paths][tests] ' . print_r($config['paths']['tests'], true) . PHP_EOL;
    echo '$settings[path] ' . print_r($settings['path'], true) . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
```

Now, run your command again to execute this debug code:

`./vendor/bin/codecept generate:test unit Example`

For my setup, which is generating tests in `<system_root>/public_html/basic/tests/unit/ExampleTest.php` from the same commands as you, I see the following:

- `self::$dir` => `<system_root>/public_html/basic`
- `$config[paths][tests]` => `tests`
- `$settings[path]` => `unit`

---

OBSERVATION - From your comment I see that your `codeception.yml` file is correct with default values for various testing subdirectories.

RECOMMENDATIONS

`$config[paths][tests]` appears to be wrong in your case - debug this and resolve the path config based on your findings.

Note that there is a core codeception.yml in the vendor package and also there should be one in your app root, i.e.

- `<system_root>/public_html/basic/vendor/codeception/base/codeception.yml`
- `<system_root>/public_html/basic/codeception.yml`

Values in the latter take precedence!